# Is there a simple way to know a list of article settings that are different from minimal settings?

Tags: document-classes, article, minimal

I want to know the differences in settings between article and minimal document classes. I don't want to do this task by comparing their source codes manually. 
Is there a simple way to know a list of article settings that are different from minimal settings?

Comment: You must read the documented source code (`classes.dtx` in pdf format). Do not just ask questions before you do the research yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy: this is all **minimal** does

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel
```

If you are asking for a complete list of LaTeX parameters with their default values, then it's quite a big job. The **layout** package shows all parameters which are relevant about the page settings.

Answer (score 2):

`minimal` defines the normal fontsize, `\textwidth`, `\textheight`, pagenumbering and pagestyle.  That's all ...